# GWT - How to change NumberConstants in NumberFormat

Tags: java, gwt, number-formatting

I need to change NaN value and Minus sign in NumberFormat's NumberConstants.
It's impossible to change NumberConstants "on the fly", so I decided to subclass NumberFormat.

NumberFormat's constructor annotation says:

> @param numberConstants the locale-specific number constants to use for
>   this format -- **NOTE** subclasses passing their own instance here
>   should pay attention to {@link #forcedLatinDigits()} and remap
>   localized symbols using {@link #createLatinNumberConstants(NumberConstants)}

It seemes what I should call setForcedLatinDigits(true) in order method createLatinNumberConstants(NumberConstants) to be executed. Then localized constants will be updated by that (createLatinNumberConstants) method, and I will get NumberConstants which I need.

Here is my code:

```
public class MyNumberFormat extends NumberFormat {
      protected MyNumberFormat(String pattern, CurrencyData cdata, boolean userSuppliedPattern) {
        this(defaul, pattern, cdata, userSuppliedPattern);
    }

      protected MyNumberFormat(NumberConstants numberConstants, String pattern, CurrencyData cdata, boolean userSuppliedPattern) {
        super(numberConstants, pattern, cdata, userSuppliedPattern);
    }

      public static MyNumberFormat getFormat(String pattern) {
        return  new MyNumberFormat(pattern, CurrencyList.get().getDefault(), true);
    }

      protected static NumberConstants createLatinNumberConstants(
            final NumberConstants orig) {
        final String groupingSeparator = remapSeparator(
                orig.groupingSeparator());
        final String decimalSeparator = remapSeparator(
                orig.decimalSeparator());
        final String monetaryGroupingSeparator = remapSeparator(
                orig.monetaryGroupingSeparator());
        final String monetarySeparator = remapSeparator(
                orig.monetarySeparator());
        return new NumberConstants() {
            @Override
            public String currencyPattern() {
                return orig.currencyPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String decimalPattern() {
                return orig.decimalPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String decimalSeparator() {
                return decimalSeparator;
            }

            @Override
            public String defCurrencyCode() {
                return orig.defCurrencyCode();
            }

            @Override
            public String exponentialSymbol() {
                return orig.exponentialSymbol();
            }

            @Override
            public String globalCurrencyPattern() {
                return orig.globalCurrencyPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String groupingSeparator() {
                return groupingSeparator;
            }

            @Override
            public String infinity() {
                return orig.infinity();
            }

            @Override
            public String minusSign() {
                return UnicodeSymbols.MINUS;
            }

            @Override
            public String monetaryGroupingSeparator() {
                return monetaryGroupingSeparator;
            }

            @Override
            public String monetarySeparator() {
                return monetarySeparator;
            }

            @Override
            public String notANumber() {
                return "?";
            }

            @Override
            public String percent() {
                return orig.percent();
            }

            @Override
            public String percentPattern() {
                return orig.percentPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String perMill() {
                return orig.perMill();
            }

            @Override
            public String plusSign() {
                return orig.plusSign();
            }

            @Override
            public String scientificPattern() {
                return orig.scientificPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String simpleCurrencyPattern() {
                return orig.simpleCurrencyPattern();
            }

            @Override
            public String zeroDigit() {
                return "0";
            }
        };
    }
  }
```

So in order to format number i will execute this:

```
String fmt(final Double x){
      MyNumberFormat.setForcedLatinDigits(true);
      MyNumberFormat format = MyNumberFormat.getFormat("0.0000");
      return format.format(x)
   }
```

But in fact createLatinNumberConstants is protected static method and it can't be overriden or substituted.
So MyNumberFormat.createLatinNumberConstants() is never executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you do not need to overwrite `createLatinNumberConstants` - instead you pass your number constants to the constructor of the super class.
as a base you can use the default number constants of `NumberFormat`.

Something like that should work:

```
public class MyNumberFormat extends NumberFormat {
    protected MyNumberFormat(String pattern, CurrencyData cdata, boolean userSuppliedPattern) {
      super(createMyNumberConstants(NumberFormat.defaultNumberConstants), pattern, cdata, userSuppliedPattern);
  }

    public static MyNumberFormat getFormat(String pattern) {
      return new MyNumberFormat(pattern, CurrencyList.get().getDefault(), true);
  }

protected static final NumberConstants createMyNumberConstants(
      final NumberConstants orig) {
  return new NumberConstants() {
      @Override
      public String currencyPattern() {
          return orig.currencyPattern();
      }

      @Override
      public String decimalPattern() {
          return orig.decimalPattern();
      }

      @Override
      public String decimalSeparator() {
          return decimalSeparator();
      }

      @Override
      public String defCurrencyCode() {
          return orig.defCurrencyCode();
      }

      @Override
      public String exponentialSymbol() {
          return orig.exponentialSymbol();
      }

      @Override
      public String globalCurrencyPattern() {
          return orig.globalCurrencyPattern();
      }

      @Override
      public String groupingSeparator() {
          return orig.groupingSeparator();
      }

      @Override
      public String infinity() {
          return orig.infinity();
      }

      @Override
      public String minusSign() {
          return orig.minusSign();
      }

      @Override
      public String monetaryGroupingSeparator() {
          return orig.monetaryGroupingSeparator();
      }

      @Override
      public String monetarySeparator() {
          return orig.monetarySeparator();
      }

      @Override
      public String notANumber() {
          return "?";
      }

      @Override
      public String percent() {
          return orig.percent();
      }

      @Override
      public String percentPattern() {
          return orig.percentPattern();
      }

      @Override
      public String perMill() {
          return orig.perMill();
      }

      @Override
      public String plusSign() {
          return orig.plusSign();
      }

      @Override
      public String scientificPattern() {
          return orig.scientificPattern();
      }

      @Override
      public String simpleCurrencyPattern() {
          return orig.simpleCurrencyPattern();
      }

      @Override
      public String zeroDigit() {
          return "0";
      }
  };
```

}

Comment: Thank you, Sebastian! I ended up writing code similar to yours, but I thought, what someone from GWT contributors team will explain the NumberFormat constructor annotation.